# Which version of Sharepoint is best for collaborating with clients?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, version

We are looking to allow our member firms who are not part of our internal company but are our clients with different email domains to connect to our SharePoint and collaborate on documents with each other. We need the best license that will allow us to do this.

We understand that every time an external user uses our SharePoint they would need a license is this correct?

We are looking to have a system where we need the fewest number of licenses. We are estimating at around `100 external users` and we don't really want to purchase 100 licenses as maybe only 10 at a time would be collaborating on a document.

Please advise!

Comment: what version of sharePoint you are using, on prem or Online?

Comment: we currently do not have sharepoint but are looking for the best version to start with to allow external clients to collaborate on documents and spreadsheets

Answer (score 5):

Users don't have to be licensed to access SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online supports 'external users', which are non licensed users that are granted limited access/functionality to a Site.

You could invite an external user (This could be via gmail, yahoo, etc..) to your site, they would accept the invitation, complete a profile, then be granted access.

Here's some more information:
https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

Comment: Corrected to ensure the right information is passed w.r.to external users and other domains.

Comment: Omar - Do i need to subscribe to office 356 as well or just sharepoint online? for allowing document collaboration?

Comment: Just SharePoint Online. Your plan would just need to support "Collaboration: External Sharing"

Answer (score 0):

If you are deployed in your data center, then SharePoint Server 2013 includes licenses for external users, that is you don't need to license them separate.  However - that's not the entire story.  You have to consider the windows platform it's installed on the SQL server it access which have different requirements for external user licensing.  Traditionally - you can to consider, configure, and in some cases customer develop the parts that will allow external users access to your SharePoint deployment.  I would not recommend trying to do this on your own but to engage a partner or MS Licensing specialist in putting this together.

The other alternative - and most likely way more cost effective is what @OmarStewy suggest and utilize SharePoint online.  It has the capabilities to share information externally without the need for worrying about additional licensing or complex configurations. There are the same security controls as you get from deploying SharePoint locally - and if you spring for E3 subscription you also get access to the ever improving data loss prevention tools and usage reports.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have any SharePoint implementation, their are couple of ways to do it.
**SharePoint Online:**

1. it is easy to setup and o infrastructure required. Start on day 1.
2. If you just want to share with external user( just view only), then no extra license required.[Manage external sharing for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85)
3. You can reallocate the License as well if you want.

**SharePoint Foundation 2013:**

1. this required the hardware and software infrastructure, i.e WFE, App Servers and Database Server.
2. You also need the Windows server, SQL server License. Foundation License covered under the Windows server. But for external user either you need a external connector license for Windows or need per user Cal.
3. You need dedicated person to continuously monitor and the perform the maintenance on the farm.

   4. But you will get more control and functionality.

**3rd option** is using the SharePoint Server but this will cost you alot.

In my opnion if you are small company then go for [SharePoint Online](http://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/compare-sharepoint-plans).